# How to store base64 image create from string in database in php?

Tags: php, image, base64

I want to store my image create from string into database in php.But there is a error.It shows an error message. The message is **Warning**:  Undefined array key 1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\drag-drop-image-uploader\create_iamge_php.php** on line **29**

**Warning**:  Undefined array key 1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\drag-drop-image-uploader\create_iamge_php.php** on line **30**
Any ideas how i can solve/fix this.Thanks in advance...

Here is my demo code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click</button>

   

  <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(){
                let text = "What is Lorem Ipsum?Lorem Ipsum is ";
                $.ajax({
                    url:'create_image_php.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{"text":text},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
            })
         })
     </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

create image_php.php



<?php 
$text = $_POST['text'];
$image_width = 320; // pixels
text_to_image($text, $image_width);
function text_to_image($text, $image_width, $colour = array(0,244,34), $background = array(0,0,0))
{
    include 'conn.php';

    $font = 5;
    $line_height = 30;
    $padding = 10;
    $text = wordwrap($text, ($image_width/10));
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $image = imagecreate($image_width,480);
    $background = imagecolorallocate($image, $background[0], $background[1], $background[2]);
    $colour = imagecolorallocate($image,$colour[0],$colour[1],$colour[2]);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);
    $i = $padding;
    foreach($lines as $line){
        imagestring($image, $font, $padding, $i, trim($line), $colour);
        $i += $line_height;
    }
    ob_start();
    imagepng($image);
    $image= printf('data:image/png;base64,%s', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
    $image_array_1 = explode(";", $image);
    $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
    $image = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
    $imageName = time() . '.png';
    $image = file_put_contents($imageName, $image);
    $image_file = addslashes(file_get_contents($imageName));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `images`(`image`) VALUES(:image_file)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindparam(':image_file',$image_file);
    $query = $stmt->execute();
    if($query){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }
    exit;
} ?>

conn.php

<?php
try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=social_site","root","");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
Table Name:images
index:image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image= printf('data:image/png;base64,%s', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
```

the printf function is used for "Produces output according to format.", it returns the length of the output, not the result of format, try change this code to:

```
$image = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean();
```